# Ejabber structures and roster

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm a new to ejabberd but the first thing I noticed is the completely absence of documentation and code comments.

I have many doubts, but the main are:
inside the record  jid what is the difference between user and luser, server and lserver, ... and ...?

```
-record(jid, {user, server, resource,
      luser, lserver, lresource}).
```

what is useful for the record iq?

```
-record(iq, {id = "",
         type,
         xmlns = "",
         lang = "",
         sub_el}).
```

what is a subscription inside ejabber? a relation between two users?

what is the jid inside the roster?

I know that these questions can be also quite stupid, but I don't really know how to understand without asking, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what is the difference between user and luser?

luser,lserver and lresource are the corresponding parts of the jid after being processed with the appropiate stringprep profile. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3920#section-3 . In short, inside ejabberd you will most likely always use the processed versions,  and the raw ones only when serializing the JID back to the wire.

> what is useful for the record iq?

it make it easier to match on the IQ namespace, id or type (get|set|error) than to retrieve that info from the underling xml each time.

> what is a subscription inside ejabber? a relation between two users?

basically, yes. A subscription from user A to user B means A is interested in B presence. But the subscription can be in different states (as the other user has to accept it, etc.). See http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#sub .

> what is the jid inside the roster?

sorry, didn't understand you on that,  what do you want to know?